# template match not applied on nested element texts

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I would like to replace a special char with an element. This works already when executing the last template separately.

```
<!-- copy whole xml -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename delement to replacedElement and only copy its text> -->
<xsl:template name="delement">
    <xsl:element name="replacedElement"
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

<!-- replace special char with element -->
<xsl:template match="descendant-or-self::text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="-">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <elementForSC/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem seems like the second template match, when copying the text of an deeper/nested element. This text contains the special char too, but didn't got replaced.

Example:

```
<body>
     just some text but - char is replaced here.
     <delement>
          here text with - in it but it didn't get replaced
     </delement>
</body>
```

Result:

```
<body>
     just some text but <elementForSC/> char is replaced here.
     <replacedElement>
           here text with - in it but it didn't get replaced 
     </replacedElement>
</body>
```

Any ideas how to apply the special char replacement "rule" recursivly on modified/copied text?

P.S. help for a better title welcome ;-)

Comment: Well, you have `xsl:template name="delement"` and not `xsl:template match="delement"` and of course the `xsl:value-of select="text()"` needs to be `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. Note that you can simplify the `match="descendant-or-self:text()"` to `match="text()"`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well the first problem (name vs. match) was caused by typing the example. The second hint was very useful and sounds logic. The last recommendation is also useful. =)

Comment: @MartinHonnen would you post your comment as answer, it solved all my problems ;-) THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the template for text nodes to be applied to all text nodes then you have to keep recursive processing alive by using `apply-templates` instead of `value-of`, i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="delement">
  <replacedElement>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </replacedElement>
</xsl:template>
```

You can also simplify the match pattern for text nodes to simply use `match="text()"`.